# About the number of $K$-homomorphisms

Tags: field-theory

> Let $K\subseteq L\subseteq M$ be fields with $[L:K]=n$. I should prove that the number of $K$-homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$ (so field homomorphisms that fix pointwise $K$) is less or equal than $n$?

The case $L=K(u)$ is easy, because any $K$-homomorphism exchanges the roots of the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$. But what about the general case? I think that it is necessary an induction argument on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We wish to prove for a given homomorphism $K \to M$ that the number of ways to extend it to a homomorphism of $L \to M$ is at most $[L:K]$.

This proof is a standard argument using induction. We induct on $n$. If $n = 1$ we have $L = K$ and there is nothing to prove, for the extension of any given homomorphism $K \to M$ to one of $L \to M$ is just the original homomorphism itself!  Now suppose in the general case that $[L:K] > 1$. Choose $\alpha \in L \notin K$ and consider the tower

$$\begin{array}{c} L \\ | \\ K(\alpha) \\ | \\ K. \end{array}$$

If $K(\alpha) = L$ then the number of homomorphisms of $L$ into $M$ that extend a given homomorphism $K \to M$ is just going to be the number of roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ which is $\leq [L:K]$. If $K(\alpha) \neq L$, then by induction the number of homomorphisms $L \to M$ that extend a given homomorphism $K(\alpha) \to M$is $\leq [L : K(\alpha)]$, and the number of homomorphisms from $K(\alpha) \to M$ that extend a given $K \to M$ is $\leq [K(\alpha) : K]$. Thus the total number of homomorphisms $L \to M$ that extend  a given homomorphism $K \to M$  is $\leq [L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha) : K] = [L:K]$.

Comment: Why do the number of $K$-homomorphisms from $L$ to $K$ is less or equal than the product $[L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$? I don't understand the last sentence of your answer.

Comment: @Galoisfan The number of homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$ that fix $K$ pointwise is the number of homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$ that fix $K(\alpha)$ pointwise ***multiplied by*** the number of homomorphisms from $K(\alpha)$ to $M$ that fix $K$ pointwise.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is a stupid question, but I don't understand precisely this point:


"The number of homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$ that fix $K$ pointwise is the number of homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$ that fix $K(\alpha)$ pointwise multiplied by the number of homomorphisms from $K(\alpha)$ to $M$ that fix $K$ pointwise."


Why do you take the product?

Comment: @Benjalim But this fact needs to be proved, and is not in the induction hypothesis. Per chance the hypothesis should be modified?

Comment: @awllower  I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Galoisfan, every $K$-hom from $L\rightarrow M$ extends a $K$-hom from $K\rightarrow M$ (and there is only one $K$-hom $K\rightarrow M$.) This hom extends to at most $[K(\alpha):K]$ $K$-homs $K(\alpha)\rightarrow M$. Then, by the induction hypothesis, each of those (at most) $[K(\alpha) : K]$ maps extends to at most $[L : K(\alpha)]$ maps $L \rightarrow M$. Hence, we have a total of, at most, $[L : K(\alpha)][K(\alpha) : K]$ maps $L\rightarrow M$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are familiar with the notion of sparability, in particular, separable extensions and [separable closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_closure#Separable_closure) and let us begin by an observation: a field homomorphism is either $0$, or an isomorphism into a subfield of the target. Hence, a $K$-field homomorphism is an isomorphism, if $K\not=0$.

> If $L/K$ is separable, then by the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), we know that $L=K(u)$ for some $u\in K$, which case you have solved.
>   Now if $L/K$ is inseparable, $K$ must be an (infinite) field of characteristic $p\not= 0$. (And $K$ cannot be algebraically closed, otherwise $L=K$.)
>   By taking separable closures, and by reason of the multiplicativity of the degrees of extensions, we can assume that $L/K$ is purely inseparable. Thus every $\alpha\in L$ satisfies $\beta=\alpha^{p^t}\in K$ for some $t\in\mathbb N$. Now $\alpha$ satisfies $x^{p^t}-\beta=(x-\alpha)^{p^t}=0$ so that every $K$-homomorphism of $L$ must leave $\alpha$ invariant. Since $\alpha\in L$ was arbitrary, it follows that the only such homomorphism is the identity.

The proof is complete now.
If some inappropriate points occur, tell me, thanks.

Comment: Either 0 or an inclusion.

Comment: An injective homomorphism is an isomorphism into a subfield. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: All inclusions are isomorphisms between the domain and image. That doesn't imply all K-field homomorphisms are isomorphisms. The first sentence, as restated, gets the point across. You could also say field homomorphisms restrict to isomorphisms of the domain.

Comment: Certainly you are right, but, as I have seen, the use of the word *isomorphism* is another word for *monomorphism* in the book [**Basic Number Theory** by *André Weil*](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Number-Theory-Classics-Mathematics/dp/3540586555). So that is why I say sorry, if the terminology is not standard. Hope it does not cause a serious problem. P.S. Your last sentence is not right, either; it should be *field homomorphisms restrict to inclusions of the domain.* Regards.